# Javascript load Two value single input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i Have created calculation Project .My code have input fields Name Estimate Property Tax . this input fields get two types of value .That Two types of value % and $ values. Now My inputs fields  get % values Only .Not getting $ value.MY  Old UI code:

```
 <td>Estimate Property Tax </td>
        <td>
          <input name="propertytaxpc" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax; ?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />
        %</td>
        <td>Or $ 

          <input name="propertytaxamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxAmountChanged(true)"  />
          </td>
        <td>
```

Now i have created this code single input value % value is default  New Code:

```
    <div class="row">

                                   <div class="col-md-4 padding-rht bdy">
   <label id="lblEstimatePropertyTax"class="pull-left"style="font-weight: 600">
                                Estimate Property Tax</label>
                                    </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 padding-rht">
     <input name="propertytaxpc" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax;?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />
                                       </div>

              <div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
                        <img src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="changeColor(event,this.src)" style="cursor:pointer"/>
                                       </div>
```

MY script for ICON change:

function changeColor(event, _src) {

```
   var fname = _src;
    var ImageName = fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //alert(ImageName);
    if (ImageName == "percent.png") {
        $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/RedDoller.png");
    }
    else {
        $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/percent.png");
   }
}
```

Now MY UI i have used single input fields % and $  both value's load single input fields .Now i get % value. if i user change % to $ value also need to change. please help me i am getting % value only ? how to value change onclick function?

Comment: you are searching for click handlers - https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: i have used click event my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand but it appears that the value is being set server side by your php code.

```
value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax;?>"
```

using javascript to change the image doesn't go back to the server to replace the % value with the $ value. I would output two separate input fields to the DOM as you were before. But use javascript to show and hide the appropriate input box.

alternatively, you could use data attributes to hold both the percent and dollar values in the input and set the value using javascript.

```
<input name="propertytaxpc" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" data-percent="<?php echo $dproperty_tax;?>" data-dollar="<?php echo $TaxDollars;?>" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax;?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />
```

then in your javascript code

```
var taxInput = $('input[name="propertytaxpc"]');
if (ImageName == "percent.png") {
    $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/RedDoller.png");
    taxInput.val(taxInput.attr('data-dollar'));
}
else {
    $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/percent.png");
    taxInput.val(taxInput.attr('data-percent'));
}
```

Comment: i want pass two value single input fields   two value % and  $ value.% value  working defaults value. Now i want change value on click single input fields

Comment: See my update on using data-attributes and javascript to change the value.

Comment: i want second  means  $ value is                                                   <input name="propertytaxamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxAmountChanged(true)"  />

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the reasoning behind a single input field if your going to change every attribute of the input. You're changing the name attribute and the onclick handler. It just makes more sense to use 2 inputs and hide the one you're not using.

Comment: Gregg Duncan i  will check your code if i have any doubt i will ask here  thanks for your help  i accepted  your answer